# Run Eclipse EPIC Perl Plugin on Remote Project/Files

Tags: eclipse, epic

I recently started a new job, where all development is done on a remote dev server. I really like Eclipse as a centralized development environment for all the different stuff I'm working on, and am not a particularly big fan of emacs or vi. I'll use emacs if I have to change something quickly, but after really trying to like it for normal development, I'm really starting to miss Eclipse.

That said, is there any way I can use Eclipse with EPIC for Perl development on a remote server? I can live without debugging functionality, but proper syntax highlighting, and the ability to create projects would be really, really nice. So far, I've tried using a remote browser plugin for Eclipse to peruse the remote dev server and open stuff into Eclipse that way, but it is far from ideal. Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: how do you access the remote files? is it a remote filesystem that you can mount from your local PC?

Comment: Yup, but I think I found a better work around. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question (which no one seems to have looked at or care about, but what the hell-- maybe someone will have the same issue):

1. Grab Remote Systems Explorer from [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html).
2. Setup RSE to ssh into your remote server.
3. Create a new empty EPIC project (or using whatever plugin/ language you want).
4. Right click the project, select "New Folder," then 
   **Advanced** >> Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)
5. Switch file system to RSE, then just browse to some folder on your remote system you'd like to become a project, and add it.

That's it, you're done. Now when you open your project in Eclipse, you'll see that folder with all the code you wanted, and you can use it just like you would locally.

The main problem I'm seeing with this right now is that currently I can't get it to do any error checking, which is too bad. I'll work on finding a work around for that and update here if I do.

Comment: This Question/Answer helped me a great deal! Thank you. (Though it's not running any files but that's for a different reason...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on linux, you can also mount the remote drive/folder with [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) and use the same "linked folder technique". I do this all the time for Java EE development. sshfs is also very reliable, unlike Windows network shares mounted on linux with Samba-Client. (Sometimes the Windows sharing service gets confused. And needs to be restarted on the remote server. I use a powershell one liner for this "restart-service -name 'sharing service' " or something like´that.)