# Eclipse Perl Remote Execution

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

This question is more to do with the eclipse than programming. But any programmer who has used eclipse should have some inputs for me. Here is my requirement:

- I have eclipse (with EPIC) installed on my Windows 7 PC. I do not
  have any perl binary running on windows PC neither I am intending to
  install one.
- I have perl and necessary modules installed on a remote Linux box.
- So, my question is, **Can I use the eclipse on my windows 7 PC to
  write/execute/debug perl programs on the remote Linux box** ?

I have already been through below articles:

http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s02.php#N10812

[Run Eclipse EPIC Perl Plugin on Remote Project/Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405594/run-eclipse-epic-perl-plugin-on-remote-project-files)

But I am not able to interpret the information given in above links correctly. In other words, it is not working for me or my use case is different than what is described in those links.

So, is it feasible to configure eclipse per my requirement as described above? If Yes, then could please provide me the guidance on how to achieve it.
If not, then is there any other workaounrd to achieve the same.
I am pretty sure some one must have come accross similar situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I got it working after a long time as below. I am kind of learning Eclipse. So pasting the information here so that I won't forget it again :)

1. Down load Eclipse on Windows
2. NO need to install any windows Perl binaries like activestate, strawberry ...etc
3. Install EPIC plugin for Perl: http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch01s02.php
4. Make sure that the Remote System explorer is installed: File->other->Remote system explorer.
5. If you do not find RSE in above location, then it is not installed and you need to install it: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html
6. Open the Remote System Explorer perspective (Window->open perspective->other->Remote System Explorer)
7. Create a connection to the Linux box: under RSE perspective, click on the icon which looks like inverted "T"
8. Follow the wizard and provide necessary information. (In this wizard, on few questions you have to choose from DStore, ssh and FTP)
9. I have selected ssh everywhere as I do not know what DStore is
10. Once complete, you should see the new connection on the left hand side

11.Right click on "SSH Terminals" and click on "connect / launch Terminal"

1. Provide the password for the Linux user and you will get a shell below. This is the ssh shell of your Linux server and you can use it just like PuTTy.
2. Now, on the left hand side, expand your server and you will get to browse the directory structure of the Linux Server. You can create a new Perl file and then go about writing your script
3. Here, the EPIC Plug-in will help you from IDE standpoint (syntax color, auto completion  ...etc)
4. Save the file.
5. Now, in order to execute it, go to the SSH shell which you have opened in above step and run "perl filename.pl". It will give you the output.

I love this method. This way you can run any script (Perl, python, shell...etc.) on the remote Linux server and can use the power of eclipse to help you write/edit the code. No need to install any Perl/python binaries on the local windows box.

Thanks.

Comment: And if anyone is wondering, this works with:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

Answer (score 1):

1. Check whether you can write a simple perl script in your win box
   with eclipse. Don't need to run. This is to ensure that you can use
   epic without a perl interpreter.
2. Copy all Perl source related to    Project from remote box to local
   box.
3. Create a Perl Project,   instead of using default location point it
   to the location of source    in local box.
4. Now you can browse project files.
5. Click on    Debug->RemotePerlDebug, from here on follow the steps
   given in first    url you have referenced. [EPIC-IDE](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s02.php#N10812)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am too confused with Eclipse. May be it is a bad choice for a beginner. I find that I am spending more time making eclipse work per my requirement than actual perl coding. I have moved to vi editor for the time being. I will explore eclipse over the weekend.

Comment: That's the correct decision you had made. If you have tight time-lines and getting used to eclipse taking time then its better to revisit EPIC latter.